# Click and If function after div change its content on user action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this markup:

```
<button id="drop_group_2" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
 <span>Select size</span></button>
<button type="submit" name="Submit" class="exclusive">
 <span>Add to cart</span>
</button>
```

The thing is that I want to block the user from submiting if the size it's not selected, so I did this:

```
$('button.exclusive').on('click', function(){
        if ($('#drop_group_2:has(span)')) {
            alert('You must select size');
            return false;
        }
});
```

It works good, but after the user selects the size the  `drop_group_2` remove the span and get the number size:

```
<button id="drop_group_2" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">42</button>
```

BUT if the user clicks again on the `submit` there is the alert again, it never goes away. How can I do that if the user selected the size (the `span` is removed) then let the user submit it?

Comment: You should check the length: `if ( $('#drop_group_2:has(span)').length )`. Objects are truthy in JavaScript!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for a length of matched elements like this:

```
$('button.exclusive').on('click', function(){
        if ($('#drop_group_2:has(span)').length) {
            alert('You must select size');
            return false;
        }
});
```

Otherwise it will always return true.